# Getting 403 (Forbidden) when trying to synchronize() to amazon cognito

Tags: javascript, facebook, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am able to login into Facebook, get an access token and use this to access my identity pool at amazon cognito. When trying to synchronize() my local dataset with amazon I get the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`.

It follows amazons [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/step2-getting-started.html?shortFooter=true#store-sync-data-1.javascript) but I must be missing some credential since it does not work. In chrome I get the message 
`{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` which clearly indicates that.

But the [sync manager github repo](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js) does not show how to add more credentials other than the pool ID.

```
function facebookSignIn(accessToken) {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: learnjs.poolId,
            Logins: {
                'graph.facebook.com': accessToken
            }
        })
    });

    AWS.config.credentials.get(function() {
        var client = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();
        client.openOrCreateDataset('Timebooking', function(err, dataset) {
            dataset.put('1', 'En', function(err, record) {
                console.log('put(): ' + record);
                dataset.synchronize({
                    sessionToken: sessionToken,
                    onSuccess: function(dataset, newRecords) {
                        console.log('synchronize() onSuccess, length: ' + newRecords.length);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I have added the AWS SDK in html:

```
<script src='/aws-sdk.min.js'></script>
<script src='/amazon-cognito.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message you are getting? The dataset.synchronize method does not require a `sssionToken` in request param, I have a feeling that it might be your problem. Can you try removing that? https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx39MLGTYNTD5BK/Push-synchronization-JavaScript-sync-and-eu-west-1-for-Amazon-Cognito is a very good example of getting started with Cognito SyncManager.

Comment: @ChetanMehta Thank you for your reply. I created a new dataset this time only selected 'unauthenticated identities'. Then removed 'Logins:' in the code. When reloading synchronize() did finish without errors and the data is synchronized. But allowing unauthenticated identities does seem to open up for abuse since the pool ID is easily obtainable.